# where does 2px come from?

Tags: css

I set a div 1150px width by javascript.

By firebug I get the html source:

```
<div class="products_showcase" style="width: 1150px;"></div>
```

However the width of div is 1152px in the firebug layout view.

I set one div height by javascript,get the same too.

Comment: are you having any margin for this div?

Comment: Is there a border set for the element?

Comment: This is likely caused by a defined padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have a border on both sides (right, left) of the div.

Comment: I add `div { border-width: 0 }`.The same is too

Comment: Thanks.In one css file I set the border-width of div to 1px;Firebug gives me a wrong information:the border width does be 1px,Firefox shows 0.